# How do I register components in nested namespaces using Castle's Fluent API?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have classes in my project that reside in sub-namespaces of some generic namespace. For instance:

- `ClassFoo`, `ClassFoo1`, `ClassFoo2` in namespace
  `MyProject.GeneralNamespace.NamespaceA`
- `ClassBar`, `ClassBar1`, `ClassBar2` in namespace `MyProject.GeneralNamespace.NamespaceB`.

To register all these classes with Castle-Windsor fluent API, I have to do the following:

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly().InSameNamespaceAs<ClassFoo>().WithServiceDefaultInterfaces(),
Classes.FromThisAssembly().InSameNamespaceAs<ClassBar>().WithServiceDefaultInterfaces(),
```

Having more namespaces leads to more code.

I guess I've got something wrong. Is there a way to register all these classes with a single statement?

Comment: If you're just trying to register every type in "this" assembly, you don't need to specify `InSameNamespaceAs`.  However, if you are choosing only a subset of namespaces to register, I don't know that there's a better way; you'll have to list the namespaces you want to register somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there's no need to specify InSameNamespaceAs. To register a subset of namespaces we can filter classes of the assembly by their namespaces' names:

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly().
            Where(c => 
                c.Namespace != null && c.Namespace.Contains("MyProject.GeneralNamespace")
            ).WithServiceDefaultInterfaces());
```

Of course, there might be more elaborate filters.